# How to search a Field.Index.NOT_ANALYZED field in Lucene.NET?

Tags: c#, .net, lucene.net, lucene

I am new to Lucene.NET. I am adding fields as

```
Field.Index.NOT_ANALYZED
```

in a Lucene document. There is one default field which is added in document as

```
Field.Index.ANALYZED
```

I have no difficulty in searching the default field; but when I search on a specific field then Lucene returns 0 document. However if I change,

```
Field.Index.NOT_ANALYZED
```

to

```
Field.Index.ANALYZED
```

then things work properly. I think there is something to do with Analyzer. Can any body guide me on how to search a `Field.Index.NOT_ANALYZED` field?

Here is how I am creating the query parser:

```
QueryParser parser = 
    new QueryParser(
        Version.LUCENE_30, 
        "content", 
        new StandardAnalyzer(Version.LUCENE_30));
```

Comment: Can you post an example of how you are indexing and what type of values those fields have? And how are you searching the index? Also, any particular reason you are using `NOT_ANALYZE` for most fields?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`ANALYZED` just means that the value is passed through an Analyzer before being indexed, while `NOT_ANALYZED` means that the value will be indexed as-is. The later means that a value like "hello world" will be indexed as just exactly that, the string "hello world". However, the syntax for the QueryParser class parses spaces as a term-separator, creating two terms "hello" and "world".

You will be able to match the field if you created a `var q = new TermQuery(new Term(field, "hello world"))` instead of calling `var q = queryParser.Parse(field, "hello world")`.

Comment: I created phrase query and it worked. but another problem is there now. If field was index as "Hello World" then phrase query "hello world" yield no result while "Hello World" returns one matching result. is there anything workaround for this?

Comment: Yes. Mark it as `ANALYZED`. You need to understand that when marked as `NOT_ANALYZED` the values are stored *as-is*. Lucene will only match it if the search input matches the value *exactly*, no impartial upper/lower case, no partial match, etc. Remember `Hello World` and `hello world` are different, as `H` and `h` represent different characters symbols, with a different byte representation.

Comment: I have marked it as analyzed but I do not if there is any drawback.

Comment: I have just observed that making all fields analyzed does effect the search results. previously when I type "a" searcher collect all matching records, now typing "a" searcher consider it as stop words. digging more.

Comment: That's because "a" is a default stopword if you use that functionality in the StandardAnalyzer. Try instantiating an analyzer without stopwords and reindex your content.

Comment: Just an additional comment - I've found you don't want to escape things like hyphens (e.g. `some-term`, escaped would be `some\-term`) if you want to see search results for a non-analyzed field.

Answer (score 2):

The issue seems to be using search values that do not match *literally* the values currently indexed; in other words, trying to match document containing `hello world` with a search for `Hello World`. Since all your fields are marker as `NOT_ANALYZED` Lucene is not processing (using an analyzer/tokenizer) the terms; it is simply indexing as they are passed, storing a string like *hello world* as `hello world`. For a search to return a match on that document, the search term needs to be *exactly*

```
hello world
```

and **not**, *Hello World* or *hello world.* or *Hello*. All of these searches will return *zero* matches. For Lucene, it would be like trying to search for the number `3`, and get a match for `2` or `4` (as illogical as it might sound).

This is why the use of `NOT_ANALYZED` is only recommended for ID-type fields where you want the search to return an exact match, not a list of related/similar field values.

The advantage of using `ANALYZED` is that the search becomes more intuitive and friendly. Indexing a value like `hello world` will break the term down into tokens (to provide for partial matches like *hello* or *world* or even *ello*) and stored in all-lowercase to avoid mismatches due to different casing (like *Hello World* or *hELLO*).